# Covariant momenta associated to higher order Lagrangians

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, connections

Let $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ be a fibered manifold with fibered coordinates $(U,x^i,y^\rho)$ (whenever local calculations are needed) and $m$ dimensional base $X$ ($\dim X=m$).

Suppose that $L\in\Omega^m_{\mathrm{hor}}(J^rY)$ is a Lagrangian of order $r$. As it is well-known (if $L$ is lifted into the variational bicomplex $\Omega^{m,0}(J^\infty Y)$) its vertical differential splits as $$ \delta L=E(L)+\mathrm d_H\theta, $$ where $E(L)$ is the Euler-Lagrange form and $\theta\in\Omega^{m-1,1}$ is an $m-1$-horizontal, $1$-contact form.

It is also well-known that when one works in a fibered chart for $\pi$, the form $\theta$ can be fashioned out of the coefficients of the Lagrangian in that if $L=\mathcal L(x,y,y_{(1)},\dots,y_{(r)})\mathrm d^mx$ then we have $\theta=\theta^i\mathrm\wedge d^{m-1}x_i$ with $$ \theta^i=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}P^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho\delta y^\rho_{i_1...i_k}, $$where the $P^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho$ are obtained by appropriately differentiating the Lagrangian (too lazy to derive/look-up/remember the exact formulae right now).

Let us call $P^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho$ the order $k+1$ *Lagrangian momentum* associated to the fibered chart.

What is also known is that the form $\theta$ is not uniquely determined by the Lagrangian, the previous $\theta$ defined in terms of the Lagrangian momenta is not a globally defined differential form and as such not only the individual Lagrangian momenta not transform in any way "tensorially" but even the total combination $\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}P^{ii_1...i_k}\delta y^\rho_{i_1...i_k}\wedge\mathrm d^{m-1}x_i$ is not "tensorial".

It can however be shown that a global $\theta$ exists such that the first variational formula holds, for example by proving the exactness of the horizontal sequences of the variational bicomplex in positive vertical degree or by applying a partition-of-unity argument to the local Lepage forms $\Theta=L-\theta$ (where here $\theta$ is given by the local construction outlined above). This global $\theta$ is however not canonically constructed out of the Lagrangian unless $r=1,2$ or $m=1$.

---

My problem is that I want to give global and individual existence to the Lagrangian momenta $P^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho$ as the components of some kind of globally defined geometric object. With the momenta associated to a fibered chart this is not possible.

On the other hand let now $\theta\in\Omega^{m-1,1}(J^\infty Y)$ be a global form which splits $\delta$ on the Lagrangian and suppose that in any fibered chart we have the expansion $$ \theta=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}Q^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho\delta y^\rho_{i_1...i_k}\wedge \mathrm d^{m-1}x_i. $$ The individual $Q^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho$ are still not the components of a global object, however let us take a vertical vector field $\Xi\in\mathfrak X_V(Y)$ on $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ and hook $\theta$ with its prolongation to get $$ j^\infty\Xi\ \lrcorner\ \theta=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}Q^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho\Xi^\rho_{i_1...i_k}\mathrm d^{m-1}x_i, $$ where the vertical vector field had the coordinate form $\Xi=\Xi^\rho\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\rho}$ and its prolongation has coordinate form $j^\infty\Xi=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\Xi^\rho_{i_1...i_k}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\rho_{i_1...i_k}}$ and $\Xi^\rho_{i_1...i_k}=D_{i_1}\dots D_{i_k}\Xi^\rho$ (total derivatives).

If an appropriate set of connections are introduced then I am looking to rewrite this as $$ j^\infty\Xi\ \lrcorner\ \theta=\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}\hat Q^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho\nabla_{i_1...i_k}\Xi^\rho\mathrm d^{m-1}x_i, $$ where the $\nabla_{i_1...i_k}=\nabla_{(i_1}\dots\nabla_{i_k)}$ are appropriately symmetrized covariant derivatives and the coefficiens $\hat Q^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho$ are now "tensorial" and can be given individual meaning.

I know that this is possible because I have seen verbal references to constructing global Poincaré-Cartan or Lepage forms via the means of connections and a similar construction is given in the book Fatibene, Francaviglia: *Natural and Gauge-Natural formalism for classical field theories* however I find the book does not have enough details when these covariant momenta are introduced and there might be errors there as well or at least the treatment is unclear to me.

Some specific points of uncertainty are what connections are precisely required to carry out this procedure. For example since the vertical vector field $\Xi$ is a section of $VY\rightarrow Y$ a *linear* connection on the vertical tangent bundle should be given, but that alone does not allow to take iterated covariant derivatives, therefore a (probably torsionless) linear connection on $TX\rightarrow X$ also should be given.

However it is still somewhat unclear to me what sort of geometric objects and structures are involved here (for example the coefficients $\nabla_{i_1...i_k}\Xi^\rho$ should probably be interpreted as some coordinate system for $J^{r-1}(VY\rightarrow Y)$ but at this point this is getting confusing).

A specific use case I have in mind is when $Y\rightarrow X$ is a natural fibre bundle, one of the field variables is a metric tensor and all connections are induced from its Levi-Civita connection as in this case the connection is canonically given and the form $\theta$ is also canonically given globally through this construction. However it then means that the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_{\mathrm{LC}}$ should induce a (in general nonlinear) connection on $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ (when the order of $\pi$ is $1$, I know how to do this, since then this is just the usual associated bundle construction, but I am not sure how things work when $\pi$ is higher order and is associated to the higher frame bundle $L^s(M)$ for $s\ge 2$), and it should induce a further *linear* connection on $VY\rightarrow Y$.

For what I want I will need to work with local formulae so it would also be essential to understand how to express both the covariant derivatives $\nabla_{i_1...i_k}\Xi^\rho$ in terms of the *Christoffel symbols* $\Gamma^{i}_{\ jk}$ of the metric as well as the covariant momenta $\hat Q^{ii_1...i_k}_\rho$ in terms of the connection $\nabla_{\mathrm{LC}}$ and the Lagrangian.

---

The **TL;DR** is that I am looking for references which construct the global first variation formula or equivalently global Poincaré-Cartan/Lepage forms in terms of connections such that the "momenta" of the Lagrangian as defined above are in a sense tensorial objects.

I would especially find references valuable which do this in the context of natural fibre bundles and natural variational principles or at least uses that as an application.

Comment: What you need is an affine connection $\nabla$ on $X$ (such a connection allows you to differentiate tensors of any tangent/cotangent valence on $X$). The corresponding splitting of the higher jet bundles is discussed, for instance, in § 5.D of Anderson's _Variational Bicomplex_ book.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Wouldn't I also need a connection at least on $Y\rightarrow X$ as well? There seems to be a notion of "fibered connection" that consists of a pair of connections on the base space and on the total space which is outlined in Fatibene/Francaviglia but this part of the book is somewhat unclear me and hence I am looking for further sources.

At least I don't see how merely a connection on the base would allow me to differentiate vertical vector fields on the total space.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are really trying to do. First, you should check the reference by Anderson to make sure whether it's really not enough for your purposes.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine In the meantime I have checked it. This seems much simpler than what I thought it'd be (I knew this text but I only remembered the horizontal homotopy operators from that section before!), but there is one problem, the total divergence terms show up in the form $\nabla_i\nabla_I(E_\nabla^{iI}(L)_\rho\Xi^\rho)$ which make sense here. However I specifically want an expression where the derivatives $\nabla_I$ are distributed over the coefficients, eg. $\nabla_i(Q^{iI}_\rho\nabla_I\Xi^\rho)$. And - at least from going through the relevant parts - quickly ...

Comment: @IgorKhavkine ... expressions of the form $\nabla_I\Xi^\rho$ are not defined if only the connection on the base is given. Still, I guess it's probably much simpler to use this as a starting point.

Comment: It seems that this is where the notion of "fibered connection" and its lift to jets becomes needed.